# Function that return true if all three parameters are strict unequal. JS

Tags: javascript, equals, inequality

I dont know why my Function does not work.
It should work like that:

```
If 1 !== 2 and 1 !== 3 and 3 !== 2 
returns True
else
return False
```

my func dont work and always returns False idk why

```
x = 1
z = 2
y = 3
function unequal(x,y,z) {
    if (x !== z || y !== z || x !== y) {
        console.log('True')
    }
    else {
        console.log('False')
    }
}
(unequal())
```

Comment: || is equal to or, so remplace || by &&

Comment: still always print false

Comment: you haven't passed anything to your method. try unequal(x,y,z)

Comment: `x`, `y` and `z` in your function are all `undefined`

Comment: because you need to put too in unequal() the variables

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 1
z = 2
y = 3
function unequal(x,y,z) {
    if (x !== z && y !== z && x !== y) {
        console.log('True')
    }
    else {
        console.log('False')
    }
}
(unequal(x, y, z))
```

or

```
x = 1
z = 2
y = 3
function unequal() {
    if (x !== z && y !== z && x !== y) {
        console.log('True')
    }
    else {
        console.log('False')
    }
}
(unequal())
```